# Spring MVC Transactional in dao service and controller layers

Tags: java, spring-mvc, transactions, spring-data, dao

I'm using Spring MVC with Spring data.

**Simple example of my problem:**

My dao Service class:

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
@Transactional
public class FooService{
    private FooRepository fooRepo;

    public Foo save(Foo foo){
        return fooRepo.save(foo);
    }
}
```

and controller:

```
@Controller
@AllArgsConstructor
@Transactional //if I remove this, method add does not save a foo. 
        //But I don't understand why, because FooService already has @Transactional annotation
public class FooController{
    
    private FooService fooService;

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public String add(@RequestParam("programName") String programName, @RequestParam("id") long id){
        Foo foo = fooService.findById(id).get();
        foo.setProgramName(programName);
        fooService.save(foo);
        return "somePage";
    }
}
```

If I remove @Transaction annotation from controller class, method save will not update foo object.
And I don't understand why I should mark controller by @Transactional annotation if I already mark service class by this annotation?

############ UPDATE ####################

**Simple detailed description:**

I have Program and Education entities. One Program has many Education, Education entity has foreign key program_id.
There is a page with Program form, there are fields: program id, program theme,..., and field with a list of education id separated by commas.

**I'm trying to update the education list at the program, so I add a new education id at the page form and click save. Through debugger I see, that new education has appeared in the program, but changes do not appear in the database.**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin/program")
@AllArgsConstructor //this is lombok, all services autowired by lombok with through constructor parameters
@Transactional//if I remove this, method add does not save a foo. 
        //But I don't understand why, because FooService already has @Transactional annotation
public class AdminProgramController {

    private final ProgramService programService;
    private final EducationService educationService;
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public String add(@RequestParam("themeName") String themeName, @RequestParam("orderIndex") int orderIndex,
                                  @RequestParam(value = "educationList", defaultValue = "") String educationList,
                      @RequestParam(value = "practicalTestId") long practicalTestId){

        saveProgram(themeName, orderIndex, educationList, practicalTestId);
        return "adminProgramAdd";
    
    private Program saveProgram(long programId, String themeName, int orderIndex, String educationList, long practicalTestId){
        
        List<Long> longEducationList = Util.longParseEducationList(parsedEducationList); //this is list of Education id separeted by commas that I load from page form
        //creating new program and set data from page form
        Program program = new Program();
        program.setId(programId);
        program.setThemeName(themeName);
        program.setOrderIndex(orderIndex);

        //starting loop by education id list
        longEducationList.stream()
                .map(educationRepo::findById)
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .map(Optional::get)
                .forEach(edu->{
                    //linking program and education
                    program.getEducationList().add(edu);
                    edu.setProgram(program);
                });

        //saving new program or updating by service if there is one already
        Program savedProgram = programService.save(program);
        //saving education with updated program
        for(Education edu : savedProgram.getEducationList())
        {
            educationService.save(edu);
        }

        return savedProgram;
    }
}
```

ProgramService:

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor //this is lombok, all services autowired by lombok with throught constructor parameters
@Transactional
public class ProgramService {
    private ProgramRepo programRepo;

    //other code here.....

    public Program save(Program program) {
        Optional<Program> programOpt = programRepo.findById(program.getId());

        //checking if the program is already exist, then update it paramateres
        if(programOpt.isPresent()){
            Program prgm = programOpt.get();
            prgm.setThemeName(program.getThemeName());
            prgm.setOrderIndex(program.getOrderIndex());
            prgm.setPracticalTest(program.getPracticalTest());
            prgm.setEducationList(program.getEducationList());
            return programRepo.save(prgm);
        }
        //if not exist then just save new program
        else{
            return programRepo.save(program);
        }
    }
}
```

Education service

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor //this is lombok, all services autowired by lombok with throught constructor parameters
@Transactional
public class EducationService {
    private EducationRepo educationRepo;

    //other code here....

    public Education save(Education education){
        return educationRepo.save(education);
    }

}
```

Program entity:

```
@Entity
@ToString(exclude = {"myUserList", "educationList", "practicalTest"})
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Program implements Comparable<Program>{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "theme_name")
    private String themeName;
    @Column(name = "order_index")
    private int orderIndex; //from 1 to infinity

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "program", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OrderBy("orderIndex asc")
    private List<Education> educationList = new ArrayList<>();


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "program", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<MyUser> myUserList = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "test_id")
    private PracticalTest practicalTest;



    public Program(int orderIndex, String themeName) {
        this.orderIndex = orderIndex;
        this.themeName = themeName;
    }

    public Program(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    //other code here....

}
```

Education entity:

```
@Entity
@ToString(exclude = {"program", "myUserList"})
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Education implements Comparable<Education>{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String link;
    @Column(name = "order_index")
    private int orderIndex;
    private String type;
    private String task;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "program_id")
    private Program program;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "education", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<MyUser> myUserList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Education(String link, int orderIndex, String task, Program program) {
        this.link = link;
        this.orderIndex = orderIndex;
        this.task = task;
        this.program = program;

    }

    //other code here....
}
```

Program repo:

```
@Repository
public interface ProgramRepo extends CrudRepository<Program, Long> {
    Optional<Program> findByPracticalTest(PracticalTest practicalTest);
    Optional<Program> findByOrderIndex(int orderIndex);
    List<Program> findByIdBetween(long start, long end);


}
```

Education repo:

```
@Repository
public interface EducationRepo extends CrudRepository<Education, Long> {
    Optional<Education> findByProgramAndOrderIndex(Program program, int orderIndex);

    @Query("select MAX(e.orderIndex) from Education e where e.program.id = ?1")
    int findLastEducationIndexByProgramId(long programId);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how you call the controller? Foo object is a parameter of "add" method but there is no path variable within GetMapping. What is more, its not the best practice to save objects within HTTP GET method. Please, use POST instead.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I updated the question. I call controller by page form with post query and change some parameters of foo object, like programName, and call save at fooService.

Comment: Can you share the code for `FooRepository` ? Why it is not @autowired in Service ?

Comment: @ViswanathLekshmanan  Yes, sure. This is not marked by Autowired because I use lombok and AllArgConstrucror annotation. This is autowired all beans through constructor parameters. In other words, all beans are injected

Comment: Mark your repository as `@Repository`. Remove `@Transactional` from Model classes and controller.

Comment: @ViswanathLekshmanan Made it: added Repository to both repos and removed Transactional from models, but did not help. If I remove Transactional from controller,  education id list not changes. I have posted my repositories in question so you can take a look

Comment: I'm trying to update education list at program, so I add new education id at the page from and click save. Through debugger I see, that new education is appeared in program, but change are not appear in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is program object created in one transaction and saved in another. That's why if I put Transactional on controller it works. There are two ways to solve the problem:

1. Without transactional on the controller: then I must save education object at first, because it has program id field and then save the program object.
2. With transactional on controller: then saving order has no matter, because saving object occurs in one transaction